# Debugging Scala in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide

I have scala for eclipse plugin installed.
When I debug I do not see runtime values when I hover over with mouse. Instead I just the types for the variables.  Note I can see the values when I add a watch but I'd love to be able to see values in a tooltip when I hover.  Is this possible?
What do I need to do?

Comment: I'm afraid this feature is not implemented yet. Report it [here](https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets).